# Not getting the access token in google oauth

Tags: php, oauth

I got the token verifier, i couldn't get the access token.

When i send a request to this link: `/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken`
The response from the server is:

> Invalid String: base string.

Couldn't guess what's wrong

This is the parameter i am sending to create Signature:

```
$arrParam = array('oauth_consumer_key'=>$this->strConsumerKey,'oauth_nonce'=>$this->strOauthNonce,'oauth_signature_method'=>'HMAC-SHA1','oauth_timestamp'=>$this->strTimestamp,'oauth_version'=>'1.0','scope'=>rawurlencode('http://finance.google.com/finance/feeds/'),'oauth_callback'=>rawurlencode('http://www.finfore.com/prem_test/google.php'));
```

And these are the post fields i am sending:

```
$strPostField = 'oauth_consumer_key='.urlencode($this->strConsumerKey).'&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_signature='.urlencode($strSignature).'&oauth_timestamp='.$this->strTimestamp.'&oauth_nonce='.$this->strOauthNonce.'&oauth_version=1.0&scope='.urlencode('http://finance.google.com/finance/feeds/').'&oauth_callback='.urlencode('http://www.finfore.com/prem_test/google.php');
```

Comment: Edit your question to add some code

Comment: Coud you post the code you're using to create the signature base string? Or the header you're sending?

Answer (score 0):

Could you post your request/response headers? You can use the developer tools in Google Chrome to grab these (Network tab), or something like [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) in Firefox.

Compare your headers with ones generated by: [Google OAuth Playground](http://googlecodesamples.com/oauth_playground/)

Might also need to set `GData-Version: 3.0` as an additional request header - not really should when/why this is required but I believe some of the Google API requires it.

You could always try using a library instead, something like [OAuth-PHP](http://code.google.com/p/oauth-php/), alternatives and example code can be found here: [OAuth Code](http://oauth.net/code/)

Hope that helps